# Distribution of the largest digit of a number from 0 to 9999

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

We choose a number from 0 to 9999. Let $X$ be the largest digit. Find distribution of $X$.

I have really no idea how to approach this exercise. Could you please help me?

Comment: Well, you must have some idea.  What is the probability that $X=0$, say?  How about $X=1$?

Comment: Right. So for $X = 0$ it's $\frac{1}{10^4}$, for $X=1$ we have all the numbers created using only $\{0,1\}$, and so on.

Comment: So, what is the answer for $X=1$?

Comment: As a hint:  it is considerably easier to compute $P(X≤i)$ for each $i$.  But then $P(X=i)=P(X≤i)-P(X≤i-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

so a first thing you can note is that X can take values 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and 9. The value 0 will be taken only one time for the number 0.
1 will be taken only when only ones and zeros appears in the number.
2 will be taken for numbers when only 0, 1 and 2 appears in the number ...
Do you see the pattern ?

Assuming that a number from 0 to 9999 is chosen with equal probability, you can compute the distribution of X just by counting the number of time X can take a given value for every number between 0 and 9999. 
For example X=0 has probability 1/10000